# How to implement swipe on views in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I want to build a movie app where the first page shows a button  that takes to actions on swipe. On swipe right the pages for all movies should be shown and on swipe left shows the favourite movies. I am thinking of using Recycler-view swipe effect on the button as it is the easiest, flexible and effective way I can think of right now.

Is there a better way to implement swipe on views.

Comment: Take a look here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: thanks. It is a good resource.

Comment: except that the view is not moving with the implementations there

Comment: You can use `TabLayout` for implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking throught ViewPager? 
I think that is the type of swipe you are looking for.
I am not too familiar into it but there's a lot of documentation of it on Android Developper on here : https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.
Hope that help :)